# How to turn blog title into a link on the index page in rails 4 using Friendly ID gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, friendly-id

I'm still very much a novice and can't figure out how to get my blog titles to link to the full post. I'm using the friendly id gem and built this basic blog following the Getting started instructions at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

Below is my current code which converts the title into a link but all titles are continuing to link to the index page for posts.The linkable title should point to something similar to this example:

example.com/posts/my-first-blog-post

```
<h1>The Blog!</h1>
  <div class="container"> 
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-1">
        <% @posts.each do |post| %>
          <h2><%= link_to post.title %></h2>
          <P><%= truncate (post.body), :length => 250 %></p>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I would greatly appreciate any help getting these title to link to the link name created using friendly id. If it makes any difference the slug is generated from the title and I did add and save the slug for all previously published blog post when I wasn't using friendly id.

Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: All three answers below solved the issue. Thank you for the help. Up voted all three since I couldn't accept all as successful answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method signature (the way you use it) is:

```
 link_to text_to_display, path
```

If you follow Rails standards, you should do:

```
link_to post.title, post_path(post.slug)
```

Actually `.slug` is not required because FriendlyId overrides the `to_param` method in your model.

So you can do:

```
link_to post.title, post_path(post)
```

Or even

```
link_to post.title, post
```

Up to you...

Comment: I don't understand this is accepted as "best" answer, as the use of post.slug is not necessary, and also nowhere mentioned in the gem's documentation. For me, using it this way, degrades the friendly_id solution

Comment: How could this be written even shorter?

Comment: @Danny, well, you did add the one... was not well awake. Cheers neighbour!

Comment: We're indeed neighbours! Sorry about the -1. Didn't know it was only for wrong answers!

Comment: No big deal :) actually almost nobody upvotes, so downvotes are a bit upsetting

Answer (score 2):

In your model, you should have something like

```
  friendly_id :title, use: :slugged
```

Your link should simply be

```
link_to post.title, post
```

You don't have to introduce the "slug" in your views. Simply updating the model will do!

Answer (score 1):

One way we like to use is to not include the attribute of the element:

```
<%= link_to post.title, post_path(post) %>
```

If you have `friendly_id` set up in your model, this *should* work automatically